# Mock Jira REST API calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, jira

I want to make a unit test not to be dependent on a third-party service like Jira Rest API. Here is a cut-down version of what my code does. How do I mock Jira object functionality?

```
import jira

issue = jira.issue("My_ticket")
reason = "some reason"

def label_ticket(issue, reason):
    if reason:
        issue.update(fields={"labels": ["label_one", "label_two"]})
        return "Labeled"
```

Comment: Can you share your attempts at a `test.py` to see what you've tried?

Comment: You can vcrpy to record the response from jira. Jira uses requests module underneat and vcrpy can capture http interactions.
Use vcr decorator on label_ticket function and the http interactions will be mocked. Make some vcr config changes to avoid saving credentials while mocking.

Comment: Came across a problem when a method does not return anything, can't catch status code to test it with vcr https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#jira.Issue.update